# Proving $abc-1+\sqrt\frac 2{3}\ (a-c)\ge 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, lagrange-multiplier

The question is this:

> If $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, then prove that
> $$abc-1+\sqrt\frac 2{3}\ (a-c)\ge 0$$

For my work on this inequality, I have proved already under constraints that it is true.

**Proof for: $\sqrt{3}(bc - 1) + \sqrt{2}(1-c)\geqslant0.$**
$$
\sqrt{3}abc + 
\sqrt{2}a  -
\sqrt{3} -
\sqrt{2}c 
\geqslant 0
$$
$$
a\left(
\sqrt{3}bc + 
\sqrt{2}
\right) 
+ (-1)\left(
\sqrt{3} + 
\sqrt{2}c 
\right) \geqslant 0
$$
$$
(1 + 1)(a\left(
\sqrt{3}bc + 
\sqrt{2}
\right) 
+ (-1)\left(
\sqrt{3} + 
\sqrt{2}c 
\right)) \geqslant 0
$$
By Chebyshev,
$$
(a - 1)
(\sqrt{3}bc + 
\sqrt{2} + 
\sqrt{3} +  
\sqrt{2}c 
)\geqslant0
$$
$$
a \geqslant 1
$$
Chebyshev Inequality requires the sequences to be monotonous. As $a+1>0$, we need to have the other sequence also in the same order, hence the condition: $\sqrt{3}bc + \sqrt{2} \geqslant\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}c$. The sequences are $(a,-1)$ and $(\sqrt{3}bc + \sqrt{2} ,\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}c)$.

I have tried another way but that was untrue. I have reached this far. The constraint $\sqrt{3}(bc - 1) + \sqrt{2}(1-c)\geqslant0$ isn't true always. Try $(a,b,c) = (\sqrt{3},0,0)$.

Thanks for extensions or other solutions too are welcome!

Comment: This might be excessive, but you could find the minimum of $abc - 1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(a-c)$ using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Which Chebyshev are you referring to? The usual Chebyshev's inequality is for random variables in probability theory.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Chebyshev Inequality for real monotone sequences of real numbers. I used $\frac{a_1b_1 + a_2b_2}{n} \geqslant \frac{a_1 + b_1}{n} \times \frac{a_2 + b_2}{n}$

Comment: @VarunVejalla Lagrange multipliers would be advanced for me. I wish a proof with more basic standard methods and standard theorems.

Comment: Yes. LM kills this problem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Any other way?

Comment: @Book Of Flames  Your trying has no any relation with starting inequality.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, I noticed. Changed the proof so that it ends in a right inequality. Please see.

Comment: @Book Of Flames  It's a very strange situation. You are looking for a nice proof for your inequality, but you are writing by yourself things, which have no any relation with the starting inequality. By the way,  Varun Vejalla and me said already that there is a smooth  proof, but you don't want to see it. You say that  it would be advanced for you. Really?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg the inequality from which I started my proof is equivalent to the original inequality, just expanded. But I assumed $\sqrt{3}(bc - 1) + \sqrt{2}(1-c)\geqslant0$ which is not true always as I mentioned. If you have a proof, you can add it. I will try my best. But I don't understand how it does not have any relation to my proof.

Comment: @BookOfFlames you should mention along with the question that calculus would be too advanced for you

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I added to my proof how I got there. Please see and say what went wrong?

Comment: @Book Of Flames The equality in your inequality occurs also for $c=0$ and $a=b=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}},$ but your assumption is wrong for these numbers. It says that this way can-not get a solution. It's exactly which I mean, when I said about relation.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, learned something new today. You can add the LM solution, I will try my best.

Comment: A nice solution was given by anhduy98@AoPS here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2311547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote
\begin{align}
P &= abc - 1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(a-c),\\
Q &= \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}c - 1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}(\sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}} - c).
\end{align}

First, it is easy to prove $Q= \frac{3-c^2}{2}c - 1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}(\sqrt{\tfrac{3-c^2}{2}} - c) \ge 0$ (note: $c\in [0,1]$). Indeed,
if $c\in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, we have
\begin{align}
Q &= \frac{3-c^2}{2}c - 1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{c^2}{3}} - \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\ c\\
&\ge \frac{3-c^2}{2}c - 1 + 1 - \frac{c^2}{3} - \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\ c \\
&= \frac{1}{6}c(-3c^2 - 2c + 9 - 2\sqrt{6})\\
&\ge 0,
\end{align}
and if $c\in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, we have
\begin{align}
Q &= \frac{3-c^2}{2}c - 1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}(\sqrt{1 + \tfrac{1-c^2}{2}} - c)\\
&\ge \frac{3-c^2}{2}c - 1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}(1 + \tfrac{1}{3}\cdot \tfrac{1-c^2}{2} - c)\\
&= \frac{1}{18}(1-c)[9c^2 + (\sqrt{6} + 9)c + 7\sqrt{6} - 18]\\
&\ge 0.
\end{align}

Second, we have (let $x = \frac{b}{a} \in [0, 1]$)
\begin{align}
&P - Q\\
=\ & (ab - \tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2})c + \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}(a - \sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}})\\
=\ & \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{\frac{a^2 - b^2}{2}}{a + \sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}}
- \frac{(a-b)^2}{2} c\\
=\ & \frac{a-b}{2}
\left[\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{a + b}{a + \sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}}
- (a-b)c\right]\\
\ge\ & \frac{a-b}{2}
\left[\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{a + b}{a + \sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}}
- (a-b)b\right]\\
=\ & \frac{a-b}{2}\left[\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{1 + x}{1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{1+x^2}{2}}}
- (1-x)x a^2\right]\\
\ge\ & \frac{a-b}{2}\left[\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{1 + x}{1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{1+x^2}{2}}}
- (1-x)x \frac{3}{1+x^2}\right]\\
\ge\ & \frac{a-b}{2}\left[\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\frac{1 + x}{1 + 1 - \frac{1-x^2}{4}}
- (1-x)x \frac{3}{1+x^2}\right]\\
\ge\ & \frac{a-b}{2}\cdot \frac{9x^4 + (4\sqrt{6}-9)x^3 + (4\sqrt{6}+63)x^2 + (4\sqrt{6}-63)x+4\sqrt{6}}{3(x^2+7)(x^2+1)}\\
\ge\ & \frac{a-b}{2}\cdot \frac{(4\sqrt{6}+63)x^2 + (4\sqrt{6}-63)x+4\sqrt{6}}{3(x^2+7)(x^2+1)}\\
\ge\ & 0
\end{align}
where we have used $3 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge a^2 + a^2x^2$ to obtain $a^2 \le \frac{3}{1+x^2}$,
and we have used $\sqrt{\tfrac{1+x^2}{2}} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{1-x^2}{2}} \le 1 - \frac{1-x^2}{4} $.

We are done.

Comment: Very nice proof! ($+1$), but could you please explain how did you find $Q$?

Comment: @BookOfFlames  It may be called mixing variables method. For example, see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2195390p16485644. I just replace $a$ and $b$ with $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$ which reduce the function value. Sometimes, we replace $a$ and $b$ with $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Sometimes, we replace $a$ and $b$ with $\sqrt{ab}$ and $\sqrt{ab}$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966306/if-abc-1-show-that-a3b3c3-frac256a1b1c1-ge-35/3866315#3866315

Answer (score 4):

If $a\geq b\geq c\geq0$  then prove
$$3\sqrt3abc+\sqrt2\left(a-c\right)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\geq\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^{\frac{3}2}.$$
Case 1: $c=0,$ it's obvious. Equality at $a=b\iff a=b=\sqrt{\frac{3}2}.$

Case 2: $c=1.$ If $a=1,$ then we are done. Equality at $a=b=c=1.$ If $a>1$  then consider on $[1,a]$  the function
$$f(b):=3\sqrt3ab+\sqrt2\left(a-1\right)\left(a^2+b^2+1\right)-\left(a^2+b^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}2}.$$
We have:
$$f'(b)=b\left(\frac{3\sqrt3a}b+2\sqrt2\left(a-1\right)-3\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}\right)\implies$$
$f$  is pseudo-concave $\implies\min_{b\in[1,a]}{f(b)}\in\{f(1),f(a)\}.$ But
$$f(1)>0$$
and
$$f(a)>\sqrt3\left(2a^2+1\right)+\sqrt2\left(a-1\right)\left(2a^2+1\right)-\left(2a^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}2}>0.$$
We are done.
Edit: Let me give further details about $f(1)>0.$ We need to prove
$$3\sqrt3a+\sqrt2\left(a-1\right)\left(a^2+2\right)>\left(a^2+2\right)^{\frac{3}2}\iff$$
$$6\sqrt6a\left(a-1\right)\left(a^2+2\right)>a\left(a-1\right)^2\left(-a^3+2a^2+a+16\right)\iff$$
$$a^4-3a^3+3a^2+a^2\left(-2+6\sqrt6\right)-15a+16+12\sqrt6>0,$$
which is obviously true.

Comment: It is a nice solution with calculus. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(a,b,c,\lambda)=abc-1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(a-c)+\lambda(a^2+b^2+c^2-3).$$
Thus, in the minimum point we need
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}=0,$$
which gives:
$$bc+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}+2\lambda a=ac+2\lambda b=ab-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}+2\lambda c=0.$$
Now, if $c=0$, so $$3=a^2+b^2\leq2a^2,$$ which gives $$a\geq\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$ and $$abc-1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(a-c)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}a-1\geq0.$$

Now, let $c>0$.

Thus, $$ \frac{bc+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{a}=\frac{ab-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{c}=\frac{ac}{b},$$ which gives
$$b^2c+b\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=a^2c$$ and $$b^2a-b\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=ac^2,$$ which after summing gives $$b^2=ac,$$ which with our condition gives $$a^2+ac+c^2=3$$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{a^3c^3}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(a-c)\cdot\frac{a^2+ac+c^2}{3}\geq\sqrt{\left(\frac{a^2+ac+c^2}{3}\right)^3}.$$
Now, let $a=xc$ and $a^2+c^2=2uac.$

Thus, $x\geq1$ and $u\geq1$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{\frac{2(x^2+1-2x)}{3}}\cdot\frac{x^2+x+1}{3}\geq\sqrt{\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{3}\right)^3}$$ or
$$1+\sqrt{\frac{4(u-1)}{3}}\cdot\frac{2u+1}{3}\geq\sqrt{\left(\frac{2u+1}{3}\right)^3}$$ or
$$27+4(u-1)(2u+1)^2+12\sqrt{3(u-1)}(2u+1)\geq(2u+1)^3$$ or
$$(u-1)(4u^2-2u-11)+6\sqrt{3(u-1)}(2u+1)\geq0,$$ which is obvious for $4u^2-2u-11>0$ or $u>\frac{1+\sqrt{45}}{4}.$

Id est, it's enough to prove that $$6\sqrt{3}(2u+1)\geq\sqrt{u-1}(-4u^2+2u+11)$$ for $$1\leq u\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{45}}{4}.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$108(2u+1)^2\geq(u-1)(4u^2-2u-11)^2$$ or
$$229+355u+304u^2+68u^3+32u^4-16u^5\geq0$$ or
$$229+355u+304u^2+24u^3+24u^4+4u^3(11+2u-4u^2)\geq0$$ and we are done in this case.

Also, we need to check, what happens for $b=c$ and for $a=b$.

Two these cases lead to inequalities of one variable.

I hope there is a solution without LM.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(a,b)=abc+(a-c)k$ where $c^2=3-a^2-b^2$ and $k=\sqrt{2/3}$. Assuming $c\ne0$, $$f_a=bc+(1-c_a)k=0$$ for critical points. Now $c_a=-a/c$ so $bc^2+(c+a)k=0$, contradicting $c\ne0$. This means that either $c=0$, or any other solutions must lie on the boundaries of the constraints, which are:

1. $a=b$ which yields $f(a)=(a^2-k)\sqrt{3-2a^2}+ak$;
2. $b=c$ which yields $f(a)=a(3-a^2)/2+(a-\sqrt{(3-a^2)/2})k$.

When $c=0$ we have $a^2+b^2=3$ such that $a\ge b$ so $a\ge\sqrt{3/2}$ and $f(a,b)=0+ak\ge1$.

For the first case we have $a\ge c\implies a\ge1$ so the domain of $f$ is $[1,\sqrt{3/2}]$. Notice that $f(1)=f(\sqrt{3/2})=1$ and $f(a)-1$ is positive. Similarly, for the second case we also have $a\ge1$. Note that $f(1)=1$ and calculus yields $f(a)\ge1$.

Comment: Where in your solution you got a critical point $a=b=c=1$?

Comment: See revised. ${}$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If you spot any more mistakes please let me know